Sci-fi anime in steampunk/dieselpunk world
I don't entirely recall the events, since I was really young back then.
The events I recall involved:

A scientist in a train with his wife and son.
The train was attacked by people trying to get the scientist's researches.
The scientist, in his dying breath, told his surviving son about his researches and gave him a pen (or something alike) which contained all of his work.
After that, there's a few years leap in time.
A woman, who has some ties with the dead scientist, is in a town looking for the young boy who's a teenager and roams around town with a little gang of his own on some kind of bikes/jetbikes/hoovers.

Any bell rung please? I don't remember the name.

In roughly which year did you watch this?

Few events of the list remind me of the movie Steamboy - train, research, scientist sending research to the son, but it would not match all of the events listed.
